# Building mathematics inside of your head versus writing everything down

Tags: problem-solving, learning

I know that some people don't like these kind of questions, but it's really important for me to get this straight.

A statement from a friend of mine, top-notch math student, always makes me uncertain about how 'many' of my thoughts I should write down with pen and paper. He said: "Most of the students I know tend to write everything down. I don't understand that. Although notes can be extremely useful at one time or another, one should always try to build the mathematics inside his head."

Up to this day, I still tend to shift between both extremes: approaching a problem and writing everything down that comes to my mind and write nothing down, but construct everything inside of my head.

The problem with the first extreme is that it might consume a lot of time, the problem with the second extreme is that I often reach boundaries that I cannot overcome without taking at least some notes.

When I write things down, I often work in an algorithmic way. For example, when I tackle an excercise where I need to start with refreshing a lot of definitions, I ask myself (and write down): "What does this mean? What does that mean? Why is this relevant to the problem? How is this object connected with this one? Why am I stuck right know? What do I really want to show here?" Sometimes, I am simply not able to wrap my head around a certain concept or step, but the moment I write a specific question down, the gears inside my head start producing answers, building connections. I even use a specific scheme for it and always try order objects depending on their properties and connections. For example: "What is object X? Okay, so, now, what is object X with property Y then? Okay, and what does this mean in hindsight of the excercise? ..."

Yet, I have found that this is the most effective way for me, but of course I always want to look out for ways to improve myself in terms of my learning technique. So, I always try to follow the advice of my friend, but I'm simply not able to work that much inside of my head, and I don't know why.

Formulating a question inside my head and actually writing it down is a huge difference for me, but as mentioned above, it may consume time that could be rather invested in developing the solution further.

So, I would like to know if there are certain techniques or strategies to actually train this "building mathematics inside ones head", anything that helps me to be able to think more and write less.

Comment: You have to be able to build the math inside your head at some point, or what's the point? You are not just trying to prove some isolated result- you are trying to go somewhere and understand mathematics. Thus you should use paper when there are details you are having trouble holding in your head and need to get straight (if this ever happens).

Comment: Of course one should always use pen and paper when one hits a certain wall, but shouldn't it be useful to extent this specific limit for oneself?

Comment: I think it's a give and take. You write down a definition, then your head starts wondering "how does this definition fit into my understanding up to this point?" Then you might try out, in your notes, an exercise with requires the use of the definition (and also of info you already know).  In your head, you might try (in your head) to generalize by leaping from that question or two or three, to making a conjecture, of how this might impact or expand your knowledge of X, Y.?$

Comment: @Borol Yes this is what Norbert Wiener did as a child and it seemed to help him much (although he also had native talent). I know the way I did things as an undergraduate is I had understanding in my head and then just used paper to make my thoughts explicit and developed (and jogging my memory later). But I didn't try to think on paper, if that makes sense.

Comment: Alephnull: and that is EXACTLY what bothers me, I always try to think on paper, you know? It works, somehow, but I would rather gain the ability to play with the mathematics inside of my head, and then, as you said, use the paper to make my thoughts explicit.

Comment: Alephnull having pen and paper is always helpful; even if you're abstracting from knowledge A to concept B, "only in your head", there's bound to be some use of the pen and paper: an arrow from one idea to the next, etc. Anyway, my ability to recall, and to see the whole and the parts is always enhanced by my use of a pen and paper.  Each person, over time, develops their personal combination of writing, drawing, completing exercises, drawing in connections to this or that. All this helps to "build"/"construct" an understanding of the concepts and how they fit with the "big picture"

Comment: A lot if it has to do with how you think.  I cannot do exclusively one or the other.

For proof writing, putting it on paper is a necessary step.  Even if it is "obvious" that the statement is true.  I must put it on paper, or I can not be sure that the steps indeed proceed logically.  If it is less than obvious,  writing down definitions is a great place to begin.

Comment: @amWhy When I was in undergraduate I would meditate on the statement until it was obvious and then ask myself why it is obvious and then write the answer down. If I had to think on paper I took it as a sign of bad mathematics on my part or that of the book (and in emergencies bad mathematics may be necessary to save ones' grade and secure future enrollments).

Comment: What do you mean by "medidate" here? Did you ask yourself the same questions like the one I mentioned above?

Comment: @amWhy I think it is very personal though. Some people for instance do math on dopaminergic substances that block imagination and can render someone paper bound. Also obviously intelligence plays a role.

Comment: Borol: Read carefully the comment from a friend who is "top notch" in math:  He said: "Most of the students I know tend to write everything down. I don't understand that. Although notes can be extremely useful at one time or another, one should always try to build the mathematics inside his head."  He acknowledges that notes can be extremely helpful, and also encourages the activity of the mind: Ask questions, guess what's next... conjecture...If you read a theorem, ask "why or why not...essentially, when you write or draw or organize on paper while doing so with your mind at work:Bingo!!

Comment: @Borol When I was clicking on all cylinders I couldn't tell you- just thinking and my mind does it for me. But I have resorted to explicitly asking myself certain questions like that (if the theorem seemed awkward or I was tired).

Comment: Usually, learners and students without insight can't even begin to notice nor articulate what they wrote in the process.  Be suspicious of any one who says "I can do it all in my head. But then again maybe only those of us who are intelligent can do that".  It is very common that math students, in trying to impress other serious students by claiming "Oh...it all comes to me easily" exaggerate their success or ease of learning, while minimizing or failing to add that they struggle more than they reveal.

Comment: @Alephnull Feel free to go to the Constuctive Feedback Chat, and ping me if you do.  But we should end this discussion here.

Comment: What is happening? I don't see any comments by Alephnull. :D

Comment: Borol.  In summary, there's nothing at all wrong with note-taking; it means nothing about one's aptitude for math.  My one suggestion:  Keep your mind engaged as you do write; try to prioritize (what's the most important concept/idea I can take away from this?)  You can write more, just try to engage your mind. Keep asking questions (in your head) as you write.

Answer (score 2):

Different people think differently, and what works for me might not work for you.  But in general, people can only keep a rather limited number of different concepts in the foreground of their consciousness at the same time. 
That is one reason why pencil and paper are helpful, especially for anything that is complicated or requires several steps.

Answer (score 1):

Personally,

- For studying: after reading, I write down (in my own style) every non-trivial proof and everything that I need to memorize (definitions, statements of theorems, etc.). Moreover, I write down examples/counterexamples accompanied with detailed proofs.
- For solving problems: I write nothing down in the process. I either "figure it out" then write down some little details as a sanity check, or keep torturing my brain until I lose interest in the problem or ask someone for help (the second case usually just happens when I'm solving a *really* tough problem, beyond what is required to understand the relevant material).